# How do I check if my single loop, single variable sorting code is efficient?

Tags: c, performance, sorting

I have written a single variable loop to sort an array and I want to know if this can be preferred to nested loops and/or larger arrays as I don't know anything about time complexity or efficiency of a code.

int arr[4]={1,7,4,3};

```
for(int i=0; i<4-1; i++)
{
    if(arr[i+1]>arr[i])
    {
        int temp;
        temp=arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1]=arr[i];
        arr[i]=temp;

        i=-1;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
printf("%d \t",arr[i]);
```

Output is
7    4    3    1

Comment: What you try to asked.... explain you problem properly.

Comment: Should this be used in place of nested loops for larger arrays? I want to know about its efficiency.

Comment: It is better to understand what time complexity is and how to find one for a code.

Comment: If the larger array contain more no. Then it take little bit more time to execute the code..you can use more loop in your program and hen it take more execution time.

Comment: It is a quasi-single loop, but when you reset the counter to `0` each time you swap, that is looping quite a bit more than a single pass.

Comment: Let's put it this way, slow old bubble-sort takes 6-iterations to sort your array, your single-pass takes 10-iterations. It gets much, much worse as the number of elements increases. For 8-elements, bubblesort requires 28-iterations, your sort requires 63.